# Loop to iterate join over columns in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe:

```
data = [('s1', 's2'),
       ('s1', 's3'),
       ('s2', 's4'),
       ('s3', 's5'),
       ('s5', 's6')]
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema = ['start', 'end'])
sdf.show()
+-----+---+
|start|end|
+-----+---+
|   s1| s2|
|   s1| s3|
|   s2| s4|
|   s3| s5|
|   s5| s6|
+-----+---+
```

I want to see if the `end column` has values from the `start column` and write their values in a new `end2 column`

```
new_sdf = sdf
sdf = sdf.join(new_sdf , (sdf.start== new_sdf.end))
```

The result is something like this:

```
+-----+---+----+
|start|end|end2|
+-----+---+----+
|   s1| s2|  s4|
|   s1| s3|  s5|
|   s2| s4|null|
|   s3| s5|  s6|
|   s5| s6|null|
+-----+---+----+
```

Then I want to join again to see if `end2` has values in `start` and write their values from the `end column` to the `new end3 column`. And so **do the join until the last column is filled with all the None values**

That is, an **iterative join along the columns** comes out (there are actually a lot more rows in my dataframe, so writing each join is not very good). But I don't understand how to do it. The result should be something like this

```
+-----+---+----+----+----+
|start|end|end2|end3|end4|
+-----+---+----+----+----+
|   s1| s2|  s4|None|None|
|   s1| s3|  s5|  s6|None|
|   s2| s4|None|None|None|
|   s3| s5|  s6|None|None|
|   s5| s6|None|None|None|
+-----+---+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is loop while there exists a non-null "end_i":

- Self join where start == "end_i"
- Drop excess columns and rename newly joined "end" to "end_i+1"

```py
data = [('s1', 's2'),
       ('s1', 's3'),
       ('s2', 's4'),
       ('s3', 's5'),
       ('s5', 's6')]
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema = ['start', 'end'])

i = 0
sdf.show()
while(sdf.filter(F.col(f"end{i if i>0 else ''}").isNotNull()).count() > 0):
  sdf = sdf.alias("s1").join(sdf.alias("s2").select("start", "end"),
                            F.col(f"s1.end{i if i>0 else ''}")==F.col("s2.start"), 
                            how="left") \
           .withColumn(f"end{i+1}", F.col("s2.end")) \
           .drop(F.col("s2.start")) \
           .drop(F.col("s2.end"))
  # end-while
  i += 1
  sdf.show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+---+
|start|end|
+-----+---+
|   s1| s2|
|   s1| s3|
|   s2| s4|
|   s3| s5|
|   s5| s6|
+-----+---+

+-----+---+----+
|start|end|end1|
+-----+---+----+
|   s5| s6|null|
|   s2| s4|null|
|   s3| s5|  s6|
|   s1| s2|  s4|
|   s1| s3|  s5|
+-----+---+----+

+-----+---+----+----+
|start|end|end1|end2|
+-----+---+----+----+
|   s5| s6|null|null|
|   s2| s4|null|null|
|   s3| s5|  s6|null|
|   s1| s2|  s4|null|
|   s1| s3|  s5|  s6|
+-----+---+----+----+

+-----+---+----+----+----+
|start|end|end1|end2|end3|
+-----+---+----+----+----+
|   s1| s3|  s5|  s6|null|
|   s5| s6|null|null|null|
|   s2| s4|null|null|null|
|   s3| s5|  s6|null|null|
|   s1| s2|  s4|null|null|
+-----+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem?