# Matching column values, complex joins and appending columns (Pyspark)

Tags: python, join, pyspark

policies:

| pol_no | cover | version | rf1 | rf2 | rl_1 | rl_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | a | 3 | apples | pears | 3 | 2 |

rates:

| RF | version | cover | rfval_1 | rfval_2 | rfval_3 | rf_amt | rf_coeff | rf_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apples | 3 | a | 3 | null | null | 0.4 | 0.4 | null |
| pears | 3 | a | 2 | null | null | 0.2 | 0.2 | null |
| oranges | 3 | a | 3 | null | null | 0.3 | 0.3 | null |

desired output:

| pol_no | cover | version | rf1 | rf2 | rl_1 | rl_2 | rfamt_1 | rfcoeff_1 | rfrate_1 | rfcoeff_2 | rf_amt2 | rf_rate2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | a | 3 | apples | pears | 3 | 2 | 0.4 | 0.4 | null | 0.2 | 0.2 | null |

Steps I thought that would work:

1. Match policies and rates by version and cover
2. policies rf1/rf2 /rf3.... (could be more than 3) or basically any "rf" columns in policies table should match with the value in RF column in rates table.
3. rl columns in policies table should match with rates rfval_1 column in rates table
4. desired output table is where policies table have columns appended from matching policies and rates...
5. so rf*1 in policies table will have rfamt1  rf*coeff1 and rf rate 1 that are values from rates table being matched. So the prefix of amount,coeffcient and rates follows the policies table rf1/rf2 columns or rl columns.

Comment: what is your pyspark version?

Comment: You can do that with two joins. Do the first join of df_policies and df_rates on ["cover","version","rf1"] and produce an intermediate df. Then do join of intermediate_df again with df_rates to produce final_df. The second join will be on ["cover", "version", "rf2"]. If there are more than two values i.e. rf1 rf2 rf3 and so on. Do this inside a for loop.

Comment: @user238607 struggling with writing the loop, how could i go about this?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma i am using the latest pyspark version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74574112/3238085  You can do something similar