# While Loop to iterate joins in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe:

```
data = [('service 1','s1', 's2'),
       ('service 2','s2', 's4'),
       ('service 3','s3', 's5'),
       ('service 5','s5', 's6'),
       ('service 4','s4', 's3')]
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema = ['description', 'service', 'parent'])
sdf.show()

+-----------+-------+--------+
|description|service|parent  |
+-----------+-------+--------+
|  service 1|     s1|      s2|
|  service 2|     s2|      s4|
|  service 3|     s3|      s5|
|  service 5|     s5|      s6|
|  service 4|     s4|      s3|
|  service 6|     s6|    NULL|
+-----------+-------+--------+
```

I want to see if `parent` has values from the `service` column and add a new column that is the `description`. Then the `service` and `parent` columns should be dropped.

This would be the desired end result

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|description|     parent|    parent1|    parent2|    parent3|    parent4|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  service 1|  service 2|  service 4|  service 3|  service 5|  service 6|
|  service 2|  service 4|  service 3|  service 5|  service 6|       NULL|
|  service 3|  service 5|  service 6|       NULL|       NULL|       NULL|
|  service 5|  service 6|       NULL|       NULL|       NULL|       NULL|
|  service 4|  service 3|  service 5|  service 6|       NULL|       NULL|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

From a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74572277/loop-to-iterate-join-over-columns-in-pyspark/74574112#74574112), I have been able to use that code for the two columns `service` and `parent` but have not been able to incorporate the `description` column.

```
i = 0
while(sdf.filter(F.col(f"parent{i if i>0 else ''}").isNotNull()).count() > 0):

  sdf = sdf.alias("a1").join(sdf.alias("a2").select("service", "parent"),
                            F.col(f"a1.parent{i if i>0 else ''}")==F.col("a2.service"), 
                            how="left") \
           .withColumn(f"parent{i+1}", F.col("a2.parent")) \
          .drop(F.col("a2.service")) \
          .drop(F.col("a2.parent")) 
  i += 1
  display(sdf)
```

I have gotten the following answer:

```
+-----------+-------+------+-------+
|description|service|parent|parent1|
+-----------+-------+------+-------+
|  service 1|     s1|    s2|     s4|
|  service 2|     s2|    s4|     s3|
|  service 3|     s3|    s5|     s6|
|  service 5|     s5|    s6|   null|
|  service 4|     s4|    s3|     s5|
+-----------+-------+------+-------+

+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+
|description|service|parent|parent1|parent2|
+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+
|  service 1|     s1|    s2|     s4|     s3|
|  service 2|     s2|    s4|     s3|     s5|
|  service 3|     s3|    s5|     s6|   null|
|  service 5|     s5|    s6|   null|   null|
|  service 4|     s4|    s3|     s5|     s6|
+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+

+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|description|service|parent|parent1|parent2|parent3|
+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  service 1|     s1|    s2|     s4|     s3|     s5|
|  service 2|     s2|    s4|     s3|     s5|     s6|
|  service 3|     s3|    s5|     s6|   null|   null|
|  service 5|     s5|    s6|   null|   null|   null|
|  service 4|     s4|    s3|     s5|     s6|   null|
+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+

+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|description|service|parent|parent1|parent2|parent3|parent4|
+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  service 1|     s1|    s2|     s4|     s3|     s5|     s6|
|  service 2|     s2|    s4|     s3|     s5|     s6|   null|
|  service 3|     s3|    s5|     s6|   null|   null|   null|
|  service 5|     s5|    s6|   null|   null|   null|   null|
|  service 4|     s4|    s3|     s5|     s6|   null|   null|
+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+

+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|description|service|parent|parent1|parent2|parent3|parent4|parent5|
+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  service 1|     s1|    s2|     s4|     s3|     s5|     s6|   null|
|  service 2|     s2|    s4|     s3|     s5|     s6|   null|   null|
|  service 3|     s3|    s5|     s6|   null|   null|   null|   null|
|  service 5|     s5|    s6|   null|   null|   null|   null|   null|
|  service 4|     s4|    s3|     s5|     s6|   null|   null|   null|
+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adapting my previous answer from here:

https://gist.github.com/dineshdharme/7c13dcde72e42fdd3ec47d1ad40f6177

Graphframe jar can be found at this location: Files : (jar[242KB])

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/graphframes/graphframes/0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12

Requirements :

`pip install graphframes`

##### Read about motifs here and here.

##### https://docs.databricks.com/en/_extras/notebooks/source/graphframes-user-guide-py.html

##### https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/user-guide.html#motif-finding

```
import sys

from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from graphframes import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession



##### Adding the graphframes jar so that we can access GraphX API of Apache Spark in pyspark
## Jars can be found at this location : https://spark-packages.org/package/graphframes/graphframes
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.jars", "file://spark-jars/graphframes-0.8.2-spark3.2-s_2.12.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()


sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/whatever")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


data = [
       ('service 1', 's1', 's2'),
       ('service 2', 's2', 's4'),
       ('service 3', 's3', 's5'),
       ('service 5', 's5', 's6'),
       ('service 4', 's4', 's3'),
       ('service 6', 's6', 'Leaf')
        ]

initial_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['description', 'service', 'parent'])
initial_df.show()

### Giving unique id to the leaf Node so that we can aggregate the results later properly
initial_df = initial_df.withColumn("relationshipId", F.monotonically_increasing_id())

source_vertex_list = initial_df.select(F.col("service").alias("vertices")).distinct()
destination_vertex_list = initial_df.select(F.col("parent").alias("vertices")).distinct()

#second_vertex_list = initial_df.select(F.col("parent").alias("vertices"), F.lit("No").alias("isLeafNode"), F.lit(0).alias("salary")).distinct()

intermediate_df = source_vertex_list.union(destination_vertex_list).distinct()
final_vertices_df = intermediate_df.withColumn("id", F.col("vertices")).drop("vertices")


print("All vertices list")
final_vertices_df.show(n=1000, truncate=False)

given_edge_list_df = initial_df.select(F.col("service").alias("src"), F.col("parent").alias("dst"))
given_edge_list_df.show(n=1000, truncate=False)

print("All vertices")
final_vertices_df.show(n=1000, truncate=False)

print("All relationships")
given_edge_list_df.show(n=1000, truncate=False)

## Creating a graph representation of the vertices and edges relationship
g = GraphFrame(final_vertices_df, given_edge_list_df)


## Read about motifs here and here.
# https://docs.databricks.com/en/_extras/notebooks/source/graphframes-user-guide-py.html
# https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/user-guide.html#motif-finding

paths = g.bfs("id = 's1'", "id = 'Leaf'")
paths.show()

result = g.connectedComponents()
print("Connected components")
result.select("id", "component").orderBy("component").show()
```

###### In the paths, you can see the path from source vertex to destination vertex and you can collect the intermediate vertices inside a list and explode them into columns.

Output :

```
+-----------+-------+------+
|description|service|parent|
+-----------+-------+------+
|  service 1|     s1|    s2|
|  service 2|     s2|    s4|
|  service 3|     s3|    s5|
|  service 5|     s5|    s6|
|  service 4|     s4|    s3|
|  service 6|     s6|  Leaf|
+-----------+-------+------+

All vertices list
+----+
|id  |
+----+
|s6  |
|s5  |
|s4  |
|s2  |
|s3  |
|s1  |
|Leaf|
+----+

+---+----+
|src|dst |
+---+----+
|s1 |s2  |
|s2 |s4  |
|s3 |s5  |
|s5 |s6  |
|s4 |s3  |
|s6 |Leaf|
+---+----+

All vertices
+----+
|id  |
+----+
|s6  |
|s5  |
|s4  |
|s2  |
|s3  |
|s1  |
|Leaf|
+----+

All relationships
+---+----+
|src|dst |
+---+----+
|s1 |s2  |
|s2 |s4  |
|s3 |s5  |
|s5 |s6  |
|s4 |s3  |
|s6 |Leaf|
+---+----+


+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+----+----------+------+
|from|      e0|  v1|      e1|  v2|      e2|  v3|      e3|  v4|      e4|  v5|        e5|    to|
+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+----+----------+------+
|{s1}|{s1, s2}|{s2}|{s2, s4}|{s4}|{s4, s3}|{s3}|{s3, s5}|{s5}|{s5, s6}|{s6}|{s6, Leaf}|{Leaf}|
+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+----+----------+------+


Connected components
+----+---------+
|  id|component|
+----+---------+
|  s6|        0|
|  s5|        0|
|  s4|        0|
|  s2|        0|
|  s3|        0|
|  s1|        0|
|Leaf|        0|
+----+---------+
```